how to do foreach over generic elements without knowing types
Is it possible to do foreach on a collection with generic objects, without knowing the types?
I have a class named Service, which the user can add to a collection. I don't know anything about the types, just the Features.Service property. I want to do a foreach on all Service elements with Feature set to Features.Service.
Service.cs:
public sealed class Service<TInterface, TEntity>(ServiceScope scope = ServiceScope.Transient) : AppFeatureBase(Feature.Service), IAppFeatureBase    where TInterface : class
                                                                                                                                                    where TEntity : class,
                                                                                                                                                                    TInterface
{
    public Type Interface => typeof(TInterface);
    public Type Implementation => typeof(TEntity);
    public ServiceScope Scope => scope;
}

Features:
params IAppFeatureBase[] features

AppFeatureBase.cs:
public abstract class AppFeatureBase(Feature type) : IAppFeatureBase
{
    public Feature Type => type;
}

What I'm thinking about:
foreach (Service srv in features.GetRange<Service>(Feature.Service)) 
{ 
    ....
}

But this doesn't work since I have to define the Service with types in foreach.
Any ideas?
PS! I know I can use new Service(typeof(Interface), typeof(Object)), but I like how the generics look better, and I don't have to use typeof().
Thanks!

"PS! I know I can use new Service(typeof(Interface), typeof(Object))" AFAICS you can't. You must specify a concrete type or another generic type parameter for generic type parameter.

@shingo jupp figured that out. I'll just leave it as it is. if it works, don't fix it

Sounds like Service<,> should have a base type ServiceBase whihc is non-generic, and move all non-generic methods into it, along with public abstract Type Interface { get; } etc

What is features?

@GuruStron I've added some more code. The code currenctly work, I'm just curious if it's possible. if it's not, no big deal. thanks!

If you want to use foreach to iterate over a collection, your class should implement the IEnumerable interface or have a method named GetEnumerator that returns an enumerator implementing `IEnumerator.
